# trig find angle in each quadrant with common reference

Tags: trigonometry

I am looking back at a quiz I took a year ago and the question is as follows:

Find an angle in each quadrant with a common reference angle with 240 degrees from $0\le \theta\le 360^\circ$

The angle $240^\circ$ is in the third quadrant so...

```
I think the answer is 
quadrant 3: 240 degrees bc 240 is in quad 3
quadrant 1: |180 - 240| = 60
quadrant 4: 360 - quad1 = 360-60 = 300
quadrant 2: not sure about it
```

Is this the right idea and am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the angle that all are related to is the reference angle for $240$, then that reference angle is $60$.

Now, with the reference angle of $60$, then it's going to be $60$ (Q1) then $180-60=120$ (Q2) then $180+60=240$ (Q3) and $360-60=300$ (Q4)

[image]

Comment: What if the given reference angle was say: 141 degrees. Would quad1 = 39, quad2=141, quad3 = 219, quad4 = 321?

Comment: Reference angles are always acute (as they are the angle between the terminal angle and the x-axis. So the question doesn't make sense, but if it was phrased as "if a given angle is 141 degrees, then what are all the other angles that have the same reference angle?", then you'd get the answer you have: 39, 180-39=141, 180+39=219, 360-39=321

Answer (score 1):

Reference angles are always acute angles and are always measured from the horizontal ($x$-) axis.  You have found that $240^\circ$ has reference angle $60^\circ$.  Therefore, four angles with the same measure, one in each quadrant are $0^\circ + 60^\circ = 60^\circ$, $180^\circ - 60^\circ = 120^\circ$, $180^\circ + 60^\circ = 240^\circ$, and $360^\circ - 60^\circ = 300^\circ$.  Notice that in all four cases, we start with a quadrantal angle on the horizontal axis -- $0^\circ$, $180^\circ$, and $360^\circ$ --  then proceed into the quadrant by addition or subtraction of the reference angle, $60^\circ$.